# Trouble with gsub and regex in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I am using gsub in R to add text into the middle of a string. It works perfectly but for some reason, when the location gets too long it throws an error. The code is below:

```
gsub(paste0('^(.{', as.integer(loc[1])-1, '})(.+)$'), new_cols, sql)
```

> ```
> Error in gsub(paste0("^(.{273})(.+)$"), new_cols, sql) :  invalid
>   regular expression '^(.{273})(.+)$', reason 'Invalid contents of {}'
> ```

This code works fine when the number in the brackets(273 in this case) is less but not when it is this large.

---

This produces the error:

```
sql <- "The cat with the bat went to town. He ate the fat mat and wouldn't stop til the sun came up. He was a fat cat that lived with a rat who owned many hats.The cat with the bat went to town. He ate the fat mat and wouldn't stop til the sun came up. He was a fat cat that lived with a rat who owned many hats."  
new_cols <- "happy" 
gsub('^(.{125})(.+)$', new_cols, sql)  #**Works
gsub('^(.{273})(.+)$', new_cols, sql)
```

> ```
> Error in gsub("^(.{273})(.+)$", new_cols, sql) :    invalid regular
>   expression '^(.{273})(.+)$', reason 'Invalid contents of {}'
> ```

Comment: What is the content of `loc`, `new_cols` and `sql`can you make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5965451#5965451) please?

Comment: What are you pasting or trying to paste in `paste0`?

Comment: I test it and it works until 255 and doesn't work for values above 255. Maybe `gsub` only accepts `{n}` values only up to a size of one byte in regexs?!

Comment: This is an awkward error indeed...

Comment: Sorry, it was just an artifact from my actual code, I use it to build the regex. Same error with or without the paste.

Comment: Use `perl=T`, it will fix it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Background

R `gsub` uses TRE regex library by default. The boundaries in the limiting quantifier are valid from 0 till `RE_DUP_MAX` that is defined in the TRE code. See [this TRE reference](http://laurikari.net/tre/documentation/regex-syntax/):

> A *bound* is one of the following, where `n` and `m` are **unsigned decimal integers between `0` and `RE_DUP_MAX`**

It seems that the `RE_DUP_MAX` is set to 255 (see this [TRE source file](https://github.com/laurikari/tre/blob/556ef09df29aadc041923522d07cc012d92a4749/include/tre/tre.h#L128) showing `#define RE_DUP_MAX 255`), and thus, you cannot use more in `{n,m}` limiting quantifier.

## Solution

Use PCRE regex flavor, add `perl = TRUE` and it will work.

[R demo](https://ideone.com/elpMNU):

```
> sql <- "The cat with the bat went to town. He ate the fat mat and wouldn't stop til the sun came up. He was a fat cat that lived with a rat who owned many hats.The cat with the bat went to town. He ate the fat mat and wouldn't stop til the sun came up. He was a fat cat that lived with a rat who owned many hats."
> new_cols <- "happy"
> gsub('^(.{273})(.+)$', new_cols, sql, perl=TRUE)
[1] "happy"
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great!

Comment: @David, `perl=T` = `perl=TRUE`.

Comment: [You don't say...](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tip-avoid-using-t-and-f-as-synonyms-for-true-and-false/)

Comment: I might be wrong, but it always worked. Looks like the issue similar to using `$&` in Perl.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew try: `T<-FALSE; T && TRUE` and understand why it's dangerous to use abreviation without warning

Comment: @Tensibai: :) I have never done that, that is why it always worked.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and that's why it's advised to not use it in SO answers (or to drop a word about it) :) (out of this I upvoted, nice digging on the root cause)